# How to stop a do while loop using "0" in java

Tags: java

I just wanted to say first that I'm a beginner so  I apologize for my (really) horrible code.

I'm creating a program where you input an int and print out the square root using a do while loop. And when you input "0" the program will stop.

How do you stop it?

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{

    Scanner InputNum = new Scanner(System.in);

    DecimalFormat formatTenths = new DecimalFormat("0.0");

    do {
        System.out.println("Please enter an integer.");
        int sqroot = InputNum.nextInt();
        double Finalsqroot = Math.sqrt(sqroot);
        System.out.println("Your Square Root is: " + (formatTenths.format(Finalsqroot)));
    } while (sqroot==0);
    System.out.println("Closing...");


    InputNum.close();

}
```

}

Comment: A variable is only known inside the block `{...}` it is declared in, there should be a compile error at the `while` line - you just have to declare the variable `int sqroot;`outside the loop, before the `do`; and just assign to it `sqroot = ...` inside the loop

Comment: Thinks about using an IDE, it would tell the problem for you

Answer (score 2):

You need to test if the value entered was `0` (I would test less than or equal to zero, because the square root of a negative number is imaginary). If so, `break` the loop. Like,

```
int sqroot = InputNum.nextInt();
if (sqroot <= 0) {
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner InputNum = new Scanner(System.in);

    DecimalFormat formatTenths = new DecimalFormat("0.0");
    int sqroot = 0;
    do {
        System.out.println("Please enter an integer.");
        sqroot = InputNum.nextInt();
        double Finalsqroot = Math.sqrt(sqroot);
        System.out.println("Your Square Root is: " + (formatTenths.format(Finalsqroot)));
    } while (sqroot != 0);
    System.out.println("Closing...");

    InputNum.close();
}
```

I just initialize sqroot outside of your while and change == to !=

Comment: This answer would be even better if you called out and explained your changes - why is the above the right thing to do? :)

Comment: Answers that contain code but no explanation aren't really suitable for Stack Overflow.  Can you improve your answer by explaining the changes you've made to the original code, and why you made them?

Answer (score -1):

This academic exercise may demand use of a do/while loop, but if you're not constrained to using it, a for loop would also work:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{

    Scanner InputNum = new Scanner(System.in);

    DecimalFormat formatTenths = new DecimalFormat("0.0");

    System.out.println("Please enter an integer.");
    for(int sqroot = InputNum.nextInt(); sqroot > 0; sqroot = InputNum.nextInt()) {
        double Finalsqroot = Math.sqrt(sqroot);
        System.out.println("Your Square Root is: " + (formatTenths.format(Finalsqroot)));
    }
    System.out.println("Closing...");


    InputNum.close();

}
```

Your program as presented in the question has an intrinsic flaw: you ask for input and then immediately try and do something with it (calc the square root) without determining if it is suitable to use.

Switching to a for loop is one way this can be overcome, because it encourages a program flow of "ask for input", "check if input is acceptable", "use input", "repeat"

If you're constrained to using a do/while loop then you still need to follow this flow, which Elliott Frish addresses in his answer, recommending you add in the "check if input is acceptable" part as a dual purpose test of whether the input is <= 0.. Such values are not acceptable for a square root op, and you also want to end the program when you encounter them, so the test can be used to achieve both goals

Side trivia, for loops can be used pretty much exclusively:

```
for(;;) //same as while(true)
for(;test;) //same as while(test)
for(bool do = true; do; do = test) //same as do..while(test)
```

..though using `while` or `do` is probably more readable than using a for loop for the same job

Note, your `while(sqroot==0)` is a bug.. you don't want to continue looping while the user entered 0, you want to continue looping while they DIDN'T enter a 0...

Comment: I'm still deciding whether to downvote.  This isn't really what `for` loops are for.  You should always use whichever type of loop best demonstrates your intentions.  Your computer is not the only consumer of your code - future developers consume it too.  A general rule of thumb is that the code between the parentheses at the start of a `for` loop should really just be an initialisation condition, a test, and an incrementing step.  Your parentheses contain too much.  Lastly, this solution calls for duplication of code, which is seldom a good thing.  I don't think you should be teaching a ...

Comment: Those for loop parentheses "contain too much code"?! `for(;;)` is a typical code golf construct precisely because it's the most compact infinite loop in c flavoured languages.. downvotes should be given for answers that are not useful/helpful as per the tooltip of the down arrow, not because you don't like them or wouldn't make the same advice. This answer goes further than the others in terms of explanation and offers complementary knowledge and alternative approach. If that isn't useful/helpful you must be a hard man to work for.. :)

Comment: Yes, I probably am hard to work for, and this code would certainly not pass code review in my organisation.  But you did ask for a comment from a downvoter (I didn't downvote, in the end, but I seriously considered it).  And I was referring to the `for` loop in the solution as having too much code, not the extra part at the end.

Comment: ps; re the "duplication of code" comment, I assume this is a complaint about twice using readInt; please offer a solution using any loop that doesn't duplicate either the variable assignment or the variable test.. Gnk's answer crashes if 0 is entered (needs an extra test to avoid this, which would be duplicating) and Elliot's answer tests the variable twice per loop, again a "duplication of code".  Choose whether you're teaching tersity or readability because you can't always have both

Comment: re the code review standards you adhere to, would you universally advocate `int i = getint(); while(i > 0) { i = getint(); }` over `for(int i = getint(); i > 0; i = getint(); { }`? Interesting; I find the while form much more fragmented, sloppy with its loop control variable scope and mixing loop control code with loop body action. That said, the house rules are the rules and wouldn't be difficult to adhere to either way..

Comment: My preference would be Elliott's solution.  No duplication required.

Comment: Elliott’s solution duplicates the testing of the variable - seems you’re arbitrarily picking what you deem a duplication..